# Is anyone running a production ASP.NET site on top of Mono?

Tags: asp.net, performance, mono

I'm trying to do an informal feasibility study for work on if Mono/Apache/Linux is realistically 'ready' and in any way comparable to a more traditional .NET/IIS/Windows stack.

Any comparison of performance would be helpful too.

Comment: I have the same question too. But for year 2012

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [companies using Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Companies_Using_Mono).

It even says that [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) uses Mono for its search facilities.

Comment: Wow - who would have known Wikipedia run some Mono processed - that is fairly impressive.

Comment: I have the same question for the year 2012. Coud you update it a bit?

Answer (score 7):

http://Fiducial.Biz, a financial company in France is running on Mono with ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

We're running a website/bunch of webservices on Mono/Apache/FreeBSD platform for one of our customers. The setup works great.

Comment: Any comment on how they fair in a performance comparison with MS .NET?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember is 2.0 of Mono is out soon (I think this week) and it is even better now. So if you do any testing make sure you at least use the 2.0 RC

Answer (score 0):

I am running a couple sites off ASP.NET over Mono. I am targeting 2.0 of the framework.
I haven't had Digg numbers, but I have also never had an issue.